# How to assign to different variables for this output in powershell?

Tags: powershell, shell, scripting, powershell-4.0

Suppose the below output was there. I want to assign to different variables in powershell. Can anyone please explain

Example::

input ::

> Get-MailboxDatabase -Server NYRTFG01 | Select servers | select -First 1 | sort servers
>       Servers
>       -------
>       {NYRTFG01, NYRTFG02, NYNTFG01, NYNTFG01}
>
> $a = Get-MailboxDatabase -Server NYRTFG01 | Select servers | select -First 1 | sort servers
>   $a.servers | select name
>       Name
>       ----
>       NYRTFG01
>       NYRTFG02
>       NYNTFG01
>       NYNTFG01

I want to assign to four variables of the four servers like this

```
$server1 = "NYRTFG01"
$server2 = "NYRTFG02"
$server3 = "NYNTFG01"
$server4 = "NYNTFG01"
```

Comment: What is the output when you do `$Input.Servers`?

Comment: It's worked. thank you

Comment: It shouldn't have. Those servers wont be variables, just strings.

Comment: Yeah, I'll explain you my needs

Comment: "Get-MailboxDatabase -Server NYRTFG01 | Select servers | select -First 1 | sort servers " --> It'll give this output                                                                        Servers
-------
{NYRTFG01, NYRTFG02, NYNTFG01, NYNTFG01}   I want to assign to four variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your responses to my comments, I believe the below is what you are after. A little convoluted but it works.

```
$MailServers = Get-MailboxDatabase -Server NYRTFG01 | Select servers -First 1 | Sort servers
$i = 1
($MailServers.Servers).ForEach({
    New-Variable -Name "Server$i" -Value $PSItem
    $i++
})
```

This cycles through each item in `$MailServers` and creates a new variable with the name `"Server"` followed by an increasing number based on the `.Count` of `$MailServers`. The adds the item as the value of the new variable.